# Proof of Lefschetz-Hopf Fixpoint Theorem with de Rham cohomology?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, derham-cohomology

Looking for a proof of the Lefschetz-Hopf Fixpoint Theorem with the de Rham Cohomology.

(I´m more interestet in the Formula then just the simple statement that if the Lefschetz number is not zero then the function has a fixed point. But the weak version would be helpful too.)

Does anyone know a book or article? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Mark Stern, Fixed point theorems from a de Rham perspective, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606564

Answer (score 3):

This is exercise 11.26 in Bott and Tu.